# Apache cant restart because it already uses its port

Tags: linux, apache, devops, circleci

Whan I am trying to restart apache it shows an error:

```
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

But when I am trying to check who uses it, it points to itself:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22656/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22656/apache2
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free the catch memory and

Make sure you are not declaring Listen 80 twice in .conf files.

For example, you might have it both in ports.conf and inn sites-enabled/www.conf.

To find out, use: grep -ri listen /etc/apache2

Keep Listen 80 in just a single place.